# Add a Class to specific list item based on attribute value angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js

Here is my code that i am struggling with:

```
.directive('mydirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<ul>\
        <li priority="500"><a href="#"><i></i>Inbox</a></li>\
        <li priority="500"><a href="#"><i></i>Language</a></li>\
        <li priority="1000"><a href="#"><i></i>Settings</a></li>\
        <li priority="500"><a href="#"><i></i>Contact</a></li>\
        <li priority="1000"><a href="#"><i></i>Help</a></li>\
        </ul>',
        link: function(v, e, a){
            var elm = e[0].childNodes[0].children;
        }
    }
});
```

All i want to do is to add a class to list items that have let say the priority= 1000. I am able to get the element but when i do the loop i don't know how to filter the attribute so then i can add the class. Anyone came around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be sending data and using a ng-repeat then you should be able to use

```
ng-class="{'className': data.priority === 1000}"
```

Comment: if this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer

Comment: Look, the whole idea is looping through these item list attributes and give the condition within the loop.

Comment: is that the only code you have in your `link`? if it is, then the second part of my answer should work for you, or will you be generating your "menu" using json or an array? Then using an ng-repeat like the 1st part of my answer would be best

Comment: both your options does not work, the second one throws an error elm.getAttribute is not a function. You can see all the code here http://embed.plnkr.co/1BoWBTRt8VtLJ7zgTYPw/preview

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="item in data" priority="{{item.priority}}" ng-class="{active: item.priority === 1000}">` put that in your template and you are golden.  The issue was you didn't have `item.priority === 1000` but `priority === 1000`, it was a bit misleading from my answer, but I updated it with the plunker for you

Comment: @i0n_za yep that did the trick, i was passing the item.priority on the list but not on teh class. :(. Thank you